# Compiling rust with cpal for raspberry pi

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, rust-cargo

Ok so all I want to do is write an audio application for my [raspberry pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/). When I compiled a simple "hello world" for raspberry everything worked great but when i introduced [cpal](https://github.com/RustAudio/cpal) as a dependency i got this error after
`cargo build --target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `alsa-sys v0.1.2`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/kuba/Projects/effect-box/hello-pi/target/debug/build/alsa-sys-967340f82a5fa569/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: "Cross compilation detected. Use PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1 to override"', src/libcore/result.rs:1084:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.

warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Its been a week and I got nothing. I feel like I've tried everything. 
What couses this error and how can I fix it?

Background info: my os is [elementary os](https://elementary.io/) (it is based on ubuntu so most things that work on ubuntu should work here too) and the code i'm trying to compile is this:

```
use cpal::traits::{DeviceTrait, HostTrait};

fn main() {
    let host = cpal::default_host();
    let device = host
        .default_output_device()
        .expect("no default output device");
    let format = device
        .default_output_format()
        .expect("failed to get device name");
    println!("{:?}", format);
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

EDIT:
Thanks to Victor Deleau I added an enviroment variable PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1. Now I'm getting this message:
`` error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1 ``
followed by this huge error https://pastebin.com/raw/ghHgpesV

Comment: You can use triple apostrophe ''' my code ''' to display your code nicely in your question

Comment: Did you used the flag **PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1** before the command **cargo build --target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf**, as suggested by the compiler ?